# Java Web Start seg faults when run with no arguments

Tags: linux, java, crash, java-web-start

We are using Java Web Start to run our java application from our webpage. When the jnlp link is clicked the jnlp is downloaded but nothing happens. No error, no popup, nothing.

Running manually for the command line in linux reveals a segfault:

```
javaws myJnlp

(<unknown>:11624): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_message_dialog_set_markup: assertion `GTK_IS_MESSAGE_DIALOG (message_dialog)' failed
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

However run javaws with any command line parameter and everything runs fine

```
javaws -verbose myJnlp
```

The jnlp file doesn't seem to matter. I can enter any file or a even a file that doesn't exist, javaws seems to crash before it ever gets to the jnlp file specified.

This is an intermittent problem. It only occurs with some versions of java, not others. But our users may have the crashing versions. I have confirmed it crashes with this version at least: java-1.7.0-ibm-1.7.0.7.0.x86_64.

Unfortunately updating java doesn't always work as multiple versions of java (ibm, openjdk) may be installed on a users system and this confuses the alternatives program into using a bad/old one.

Any thoughts on how we can prevent this crash would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same symptom using oracle jdk. Seems to occur when IcedTea was previously used by error, and interrupted.

Removing `~/.java/deployment/config.cache` corrects the problem, although the only difference is a timestamp.